# Copy/Paste progress bar

Tags: windows, copy-paste

Sometimes I'm copy/pasting large numbers of text entries within one editor or between different editors (currently I'm pasting over 4.8 million entries and I'm waiting for several minutes already).

Within Windows environment, is there a progress bar present which I can enable (via some registry setting) in order to see the progress of large paste command executions?

Comment: no, there is not any progress bar which you could enable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunetly not.

How it works?
1. The source software (where you press Ctrl-C) collect the data (slow, collect selected cells/text, image contents, hidden values etc),
may format it to meet clipboard's requirements (slow) and move the produced
data to the clipboard (like a thunder)
2. The target software (where you press Ctrl-V) get the clipboard data
(same as thunder), analize it, convert it to target software own format,
and fill the target space (much slow, because need to update the user
interface too, fill cells, format text/images, lot of drawing).

So monitoring clipboard progress has no reason, that part of the operation
is really fast, progress bar should be used in the source/target software
inside.

Comment: What a pity, it would have been a nice feature, but thanks for the information.

Comment: It's depend on the software, not on OS.  What I wrote in answer is the generic method, there's another copy-paste flows, but it related to OS, not the user's softwares.